# MyBatis Collection Mapping Issue Based on Column Order

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I am having an issue when creating a collection of columns from multiple rows based on a specific id using MyBatis.

Here's the problematic MyBatis code:

```sql
<resultMap id="testMap" type="Test">
    <result property="no" column="no"/>
    <collection property="datelist" column= "date" ofType="String" />
</resultMap>

<select id="test" parameterType="int" resultMap= "testMap">
    select 1 as no, '202301' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202302' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202303' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202304' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202305' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202306' as date
    UNION
    select 1 as no, '202307' as date
</select>
```

The result type of resultMap is:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Test {
    private int no;
    private List<String> datelist;
}
```

I expect the result of this query to be mapped to the Test object as follows:

```json
{
    "no": 1,
    "datelist": [
        "202301",
        "202302",
        "202303",
        "202304",
        "202305",
        "202306",
        "202307"
    ]
}
```

However, the actual Test object that comes out from the query is:

```json
{
    "no": 1,
    "datelist": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ]
}
```

After various tests, I discovered a peculiar behavior: if I change the order of columns in the select query, it outputs correctly:

```sql
<select id="test" parameterType="int" resultMap= "testMap">
    select '202302' as date, 1 as no
    UNION
    select '202303' as date, 1 as no
    UNION
    select '202304' as date, 1 as no
    UNION
    select '202305' as date, 1 as no
    UNION
    select '202306' as date, 1 as no
    UNION
    select '202307' as date, 1 as no
</select>
```

The Test object from this query is:

```json
{
    "no": 1,
    "datelist": [
        "202301",
        "202302",
        "202303",
        "202304",
        "202305",
        "202306",
        "202307"
    ]
}
```

Is this just a data processing issue within MyBatis? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: There is a [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-map-a-list-of-simple-type-objects-string-integer-etc-to-a-bean-or-map-) for that mapping.